# Uniform sampling of k integers from [0:n)

Tags: algorithm, random, uniform-distribution

My goal is to sample k integers from 0, ... n-1 without duplication. The order of sampled integers doesn't matter. At every each call (which occurs very often), n and k will slightly vary but not much (n is about 250,000 and k is about 2,000). I've come up with the following amortized O(k) algorithm:

1. Prepare an array A with items 0, 1, 2, ... , n-1. This takes O(n) but since n is relatively stable, the cost can be made amortized constant.
2. Sample a random number r from [0:i] where i = n - 1. Here the cost is in fact related to n, but as n is not VERY BIG, this dependency is not critical.
3. Swap the rth item and the ith item  in the array A.
4. Decrease i by 1.
5. Repeat k times the steps 2~4; now we have a random permutation of length k at the tail of A. Copy this.
6. We should roll back A to its initial state (0, ... , n-1) to keep the cost of the step 1 constant. This can be done by push r to a stack of length k at each pass of step 2. Preparation of the stack requires amortized constant cost.

I think uniform sampling of permutation/combination should be an exhaustively studied problem, so either (1) there is a much better solution, or at least (2) my solution is a (minor modification of) a well-known solution. Thus,

- In case (1), I want to know that better solution.
- In case (2), I want to find a reference.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Your approach is kind of Fisher-Yates shuffle. It is not clear - why do you need to rollback?

Comment: ad 1. if n is bounded then you only need to create the array once (provided you get back to order at the end, which you suggest); ad 2. i fail to see how it is related to n, taking a random number in range is O(1); ad 6. you don't need a separate stack since you have the solution at the end of the array.

Comment: @Mbo rolling back is O(k) way to "recreate" an ordered array of size n in this case

Comment: @Sopel About 2: I'm not sure it really takes some cost, but I think if "really uniformly random" sampling is needed, then there may be some cost related to n. And, can you explain how can I roll back using the permutation created?

Comment: @MBo Thanks! It seems that my approach is called  "Durstenfeld's version" of Fisher-Yates shuffle, according to wikipedia.

Comment: @JunekeyJeon  1 2 3 4 -> 1 4 3 `2` -> 1 3 `4 2` -> 3 `1 4 2`; now you iterate through the chosen values (let's name currently checked one `v`, and its index `i`) and mark `A[v] = v` and `A[i] = i`; so 3 `1 4 2` -> 1 2 `4 2` -> 1 2 3 `4` -> 1 2 3 `4`

Comment: @Sopel Sorry... but I can't catch what are v and i exactly.

Comment: @JunekeyJeon let A[] = [2 `1`] (`xxx` marks the number we randomized (there may be k of them)). You loop through all of them and do what i described earlier, so in this case A[1] = 1 because the randomized number is 1 and A[2] = 2 because the randomized number is on the index 2. (i'm using 1-based indexing for simplicity) It fill both the place currently checked and the place where we took the number from, so it ends up ordered again.

Comment: Seems that @Sopel talks about restoration of initial state using decomposition of permutation into disjoint cycles

Comment: @MBo Disjoint cycles.. that makes sense, but... @Sopel How about this?   1 2 3 4 -> 4 2 3 `1` -> 3 2 `4 1`. As I understood, rolling back goes as: 3 2 `4 1` -> 3 2 3 `4` -> 3 2 3 4...?

Comment: @JunekeyJeon yea, there seems to be a flaw in my thinking. I was thinking about one way, then simplified it and thought it is still valid. The solution i initially thought of is repeatadly swapping the values with their original position until they are ordered, so it would go like: 3 2 `**4** 1` -> 3 2 `**1** 4` -> 1 2 `**3** 4` (3 on its place, move to the next one) -> 1 2 3 `**4**` -> 1 2 3 4, that way you can't lose them; sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Sopel Hmm.. Checking that they are ordered takes O(k), so rolling back takes in total O(k^2). Seems like a bad idea, isn't it? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @JunekeyJeon you don't have to move back and you only move further if the current one is already correct. It's what MBo was talking about

Comment: @Sopel Seems like you were moving the pivot from v to A[v] and stopped at 1 2 `**3** 4` because 3 is now at the correct position. Am I right? But what if there are still other cycles that should be rolled back? How can I determine where to start with then?

Comment: Oh. It was indeed simple. Just take each cycle starting from n-k, ... , n-1 and reverse it in that order. Then this will take less then 2k swaps.

Comment: Congratulations! You've rediscovered Fisher-Yates-Knuth shuffle, in Durstenfeld's implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If `k` is much less than `n` -- say, less than half of `n` -- then the most efficient solution is to keep the numbers generated in a hash table (actually, a hash set, since there is no value associated with a key). If the random number happens to already be in the hash table, reject it and generate another one in its place. With the actual values of `k` and `n` suggested (`k ∼ 2000; n ∼ 250,000`) the expected number of rejections to generate `k` unique samples is less than 10, so it will hardly be noticeable. The size of the hash table is O(k), and it can simply be deleted at the end of the sample generation.
2. It is also possible to simulate the FYK shuffle algorithm using a hash table instead of a vector of `n` values, thereby avoiding having to reject generated random numbers. If you were using a vector `A`, you would start by initializing `A[i]` to `i`, for every `0 ≤ i < k`. With the hash table `H`, you start with an empty hash table, and use the convention that `H[i]` is considered to be `i` if the key `i` is not in the hash table. Step 3 in your algorithm -- "swap `A[r]` with `A[i]`" -- becomes "add `H[r]` as the next element of the sample and set `H[r]` to `H[i]`". Note that it is unnecessary to set `H[i]` because that element will never be referred to again: all subsequent random numbers `r` are generate from a range which does not include `i`.

   Because the hash table in this case contains both keys and values, it is larger than the hash set used in alternative 1, above, and the increased size (and consequent increase in memory cache misses) is likely to cause more overhead than is saved by eliminating rejections. However, it has the advantage of working even if `k` is occasionally close to `n`.
3. Finally, in your proposed algorithm, it is actually quite easy to restore `A` in O(k) time. A value `A[j]` will have been modified by the algorithm only if:

   a. `n − k ≤ j < n`, or

   b. there is some `i` such that `n − k ≤ i < n` and  `A[i] = j`.

   Consequently, you can restore the vector `A` by looking at each `A[i]` for `n − k ≤ i < n`: first, if `A[i] < n−k`, set `A[A[i]]` to `A[i]`; then, unconditionally set `A[i]` to `i`.

Comment: 1. I can't see any advantage of using hash table over vector. For the method 1, I think it is better to use a vector of flags. Indeed, it was faster than FYK-style algorithms for small k, but expected number of rejections is (a little more than) k(k-1)/2(n-1), so it indeed grows quite fast. Also, it depends more heavily on performance of random number generation, which can be very expensive if reaaaaally random behaviour is necessaey. For the method 2, still I couldn't find out what's offered better by hash table.

Comment: 2. What you described in 3 seems really good. Additionally, as I said in the question I'm not care about the order of generation (combinations rather than permutations), so if k is larger than n/2 than method 1 can be still applied to (n,n-k) rather than (n,k). Consequently, the best is perhaps: (1) Use method 1 if k is very small (2) Use method 1 with n-k if k is very large (3) Use method 2 otherwise. Thanks!

Comment: I've made a simple experiment... It seems that dependency of the method 2 on k for fixed ratio k/n is harsher than that of method 1, although theoretically both should depend linearly on k when k/n is fixed. As you said, increased chance of cache miss was an important factor to this.

Comment: @junekey: for moderate values of `n`, a bit vector will perform better than a hash set; I should have mentioned that. The advantage of the hash table is that its size is O(k) rather than O(n); for large `n` (say, 64-bit numbers), that becomes important. But if you know that `n` is not too big, I agree.

Comment: @junekey: the second hashtable solution is mostly a curiosity, but as I said it has the advantage of flexibility. For any `n, k` there is a faster solution, but the hash table offers reasonable performance for any `n, k`. My trial implementation used a cuckoo hash, which was much more performant than a chained-hash, but for `k` small relative to `n`, rejection sampling always wins.

Comment: @junekey, finally: the cost of rejection sampling is O(k), because k*k/n is less than k, given that k/n is less than 1. (However, that approximation is not valid if k is close to n.) If k is n/2, the expected number of rejections for the kth value is exactly 1; obviously the expected number of rejections for earlier values is less. So if you know k is not more than n/2, rejection sampling is going to require less than twice as many random numbers. But on the plus side, they are all in the same range, which offers a small saving.